# How to update existing changeset

Tags: liquibase

I want to update very old changeset because there is a bug in that. I have updated that changesetid and After running it I got checksum error i.e checksum got modified. Now I have added validCheckSum Tag with this new checkSum. After it is getting successfully I cant not see new changes. Is there any way to update that change set which has already been executed.

Comment: The easiest way is to give it a new changesetId

Comment: The golden rule is: don't do it.

Comment: Could you please give  detail explanation? So there is no way to update existing changeset since it will skip all the time. Then if I ll give new changeset Id what problem I could face @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `changeSet` tag is uniquely identified by the combination of the “id” tag, the “author” tag so please check whether `id` and `author name` already exists or not in `DATABASECHANGELOG` table. If the combination exists then change the `id` in your xml file then run the build

If still not works then add `runOnChange` property in `<ChangeSet>` and try it

> runOnChange - Executes if any changes found it already existing changeset

Comment: be careful if you put runOnChange it will always execute, even after applying the change.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a very old changeset as you have stated you should consider not changing the old changeset but add a new changeset instead which fixes the bug since it allows you better control over the versions you have. This is one of the main reasons of using liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using **runOnChange** in changeset with sqlFile tag .
I had a script for Oracle 18 using IDENTITY column type and than have to change it for Oracle 10 which doesn't support IDENTITY column type

```
 <changeSet id="2" author="auto" runOnChange="true">
        <sqlFile dbms="oracle" encoding="utf8" endDelimiter=";" path="oracle/230.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true" />
  </changeSet>
```